# Is it necessary to watch Black Panther before watching Avengers-Infinity War

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, suggested-order, black-panther

I watched all the movies related to Marvel Cinematic Universe except *Black Panther* and *Avengers: Infinity War* and now I am planning to watch the latter.

Does *Black Panther* have that much influence on *Avengers: Infinity War* which can spoil the following of the latter's plot?

Comment: Already answered [What films to watch before Avengers: Infinity War for better understanding?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/83268/48608)

Comment: @NogShine Not exactly, That answer *pre-dates* Black Panther and assumes that Wakanda will be important.

Comment: @NogShine I am not asking about order of watching movies before you watch Infinity war but asking about if there are important points that are mentioned in BP which I have to know ?

Comment: For that also, [tag:suggested-order] is right tag.

Comment: @Paulie_D That means it might need newer answers, now that people have seen the actual film and not just a trailer.

Comment: I'd suggest that it might be better for @KutuluMike to edit that answer rather than me edit it for him at least initially. Has he been around lately?

Comment: @Paulie_D It seems he already *has* edited in response to *Infinity War*.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## **No...**

There are no **essential** plot points in *Black Panther* that you absolutely need to follow the plot of *Infinity War*.

---

### ..and Yes

That said, there are characters, relationships and technology etc. that are fairly prominent in the latter parts of IW (when Thanos arrives in Wakanda) that you will not be aware of.

Whether this lack of familiarity with *Black Panther* will spoil watching *Infinity War* for you is a subjective thing.

Comment: As someone who decided against watching black panther before infinity war, purely because it was hard to see black panther, you don't feel like your not getting anything, but theres certainly the feeling that your missing out on the backstory of a few of the more important characters, later on.

Comment: I agree with this answer. Obviously, some of the big reveals (like entering wakanda for the first time), will be ruined if you watch IF first. But, plot-wise, you will miss virtually nothing.

Answer (score 9):

**Yes**

I will strongly recommend.

The final fight occur in the place called Wakanda and lots of Wakanda people take part in it. Without having knowledge about them, they will look like extras and understanding Wakanda will be tough. It is better shown in *Black Panther*.

And why they go to Wakanda and not some other place will also be better cleared if you have seen Black Panther. Even Black Panther end credit scene is important to know the fate of a certain character and how he came back in this film all of sudden.

Comment: The fate of the character you mention in the end credit scene is already revealed in the post-credit from Captain America: Civil War

Comment: @Gronalak partially yes but how shuri did that and why shuri able to do that is better understandable after black panther.

Comment: @Gronalak: you should add this as an answer.

Comment: @Taladris I don't think this is an answer to the OP's question, as he strictly mention Black Panther (and he apparently saw Civil War)