# Which prior MCU films are specifically travelled to, or called out in Endgame?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

This is NOT a duplicate of:

- [What is the MCU film "Critical Path" to get proper backstory before watching Avengers: Endgame?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/97808/what-is-the-mcu-film-critical-path-to-get-proper-backstory-before-watching-ave)
  ("Contextual backstory" is different from "they visit it, or visually call it out")
- [Is there any particular order in which one should watch the movies of Marvel Cinematic Universe? Why?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60832/is-there-any-particular-order-in-which-one-should-watch-the-movies-of-marvel-cin) (I'm definitely not talking about watching all of MCU, and certainly not what order to watch it in)

---

I've watched Endgame, and all of the prior MCU, and thoroughly enjoyed all the visual callbacks. If I wanted to show a non-devotee the film and have them 'get' all the references, then what would they need to have seen?

Creating this as a wiki answer.

Comment: I'm inclined to think this is too broad since practically every MCU property (Netflix & AoS aside)  is referenced in the movie.

Answer (score 8):

## Visited

- *Avengers (Assemble)*

  - Battle of New York: famous circle scene.
  - Finale cornering Loki at top of Stark Tower scene.
- *Thor: Dark World*

  - Thor sneaking across the prison floor in front of Loki.
  - Talking to his mother
- *Guardians of The Galaxy (Vol. 1)*

  - Star Lord originally stealing the Power Stone.

## Referenced

- *Iron Man*

  - "I am Iron Man" final line
  - Post-credits clanks
- *CA: First Avenger*

  - Dancing with Peggy
  - Seeing Peggy in the 70's military base.
  - Red Skull introduced and teleported to Vormir (arguably a retcon)
- *CA: Winter Soldier*

  - SHIELD Strike Team
  - Elevator scene
  - Hail Hydra
  - Pierce in the lobby.
- *Avengers: Infinity War*

  - Thor going for the head.
- *Agent Carter*

  - Jarvis introduced (he appears in 1970)

Comment: Hm, actually I edited in the IM line but I'm not sure whether that falls into what you meant?